# Save data from a checkbox to a wpdb array

Tags: wpdb, array

I have several fruit checkboxes but when saving to the wpdb database it only saves the last one that it checks, variable $check receives vardump string (6) "banana" string (5) "apple"

In the database only appears apple should be banana, apple in that same field an array. Should not only save it the last marked

```
 foreach( $checkboxes as $check ) {
    var_dump( $check); 
}

 global $wpdb; 
 $wpdb->insert('data',array( 
      'fruit' => $check
    ));
```

Comment: Then you should be inserting `$checkboxes`, not `$check`, which can only be one item because it's created in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Wordpress question this is a PHP question. Your `foreach` loops through all the `$checkboxes` putting one in the `$check` variable each time, so your `insert()` call only inserts the last value for `$check`, because it's not inside that `foreach` loop.

You probably want:

```
global $wpdb; 
foreach( $checkboxes as $check ) {
    $wpdb->insert('data',array('fruit' => $check));
}
```